# Keeping an object within the screen. Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am new to swift a Sprite kit. In the app I am trying to make I have a submarine moving through the ocean. Every time the user clicks the screen the gravity starts pulling the sub in the opposite direction. My problem is that i can't find a way to keep the sub from leaving the screen. I have tried to solve it by making a physicsBody around the screen, but the sub still leaves the screen. I have also tried the following code in the        updateCurrentTime fund.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,gravity)

    if (sub.position.y >= self.size.height - sub.size.height / 2){
       sub.position.y = self.size.height - self.sub.size.height / 2
    }
    if (sub.position.y <= sub.size.height / 2) {
        sub.position.y = self.sub.size.height / 2

    }



}
```

But this doesn't do anything either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!! thanks in advance!
P.S. I can't believe that it is that hard to keep things on the screen!!!
frustrating!

Comment: I found that adding:  let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size) to the gameViewController makes the edgeLoopFromRect around the screen method work, but it makes the entire view do a zooming in affect, and I'm not really sure what it does, so i don't want to use it. Can some one explain to me what this is supposed to do, and why it makes the view zoom in/ make sub bigger. also it turns the background black....?

Comment: Initialising the GameScene like that means that it isn't loaded from an sks file. It makes the scene the right size for the screen (so the edge loop is on the edges of the screen), you should change the scene size in your sks file (default is around 1000x800) so that is why it is scaled to be smaller.

Comment: Hi BoB, the zooming can be dealt with by setting the scaleMode of the scene as required i.e. `scene!.scaleMode = .AspectFit` .  Setting the sks file scene size to the screen dimensions is also a good idea for convenience sake.

Comment: Have you tried adding a physics body on the bottom of the screen? making the submarine collide with this body and therefore not going any deeper. Remember to set `.dynamic` property to `false` to this bottom object.

Comment: You use SKConstraint for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try `SKConstraint` - it doesn't require a physicsBody. The code would look something like this, and would constrain the `sub` sprite to the scene:

```
let width2 =  sub.size.width/2
let height2 =  sub.size.height/2
let xRange = SKRange(lowerLimit:0+width2,upperLimit:size.width-width2)
let yRange = SKRange(lowerLimit:0+height2,upperLimit:size.height-height2)
sub.constraints = [SKConstraint.positionX(xRange,Y:yRange)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in the update:

```
if sub.frame.maxY >= view!.frame.height {
    sub.position.y = view!.frame.height - sub.size.height / 2
    sub.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
}
if sub.frame.minY <= 0 {
    sub.position.y = sub.size.height / 2
    sub.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
}
```

And then inside of the event where you want to reverse gravity don't forget to do this:

```
sub.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
```

Alternatively, instead of using gravity you could use this which is a better option in my opinion:

```
// This moves the object to the top of the screen
let action = SKAction.moveToY(view!.frame.height - character.size.height / 2, duration: 5.0) // Or however much time you want to the action to run.
action.timingMode = .EaseInEaseOut // Or something else
character.runAction(action)
 // Change view!.frame.height - character.size.height / 2 to just character.size.height / 2 to move to the bottom.
```