# Prevent SCNNode from going out of the screen

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I'm playing around with ARKit and SceneKit.

I have a node A - this is the only node that I've added to the rootNode. Node A is allowed to move freely by moving the phone around, except that it's not allowed to leave the screen.

To achieve that (prevent node A from leaving the screen), I can think of the following ways:

1. Add a transform constraint to node A: I've tried to do it in the following manner:

> ```
> [SCNTransformConstraint  transformConstraintInWorldSpace:false  withBlock:^SCNMatrix4(SCNNode * _Nonnull node, SCNMatrix4 transform) {
>      bool visible = [self.sceneView isNodeInsideFrustum:node withPointOfView:self.cameraNode];
>      if (visible) {
>          NSLog(@"visible=%d", visible);
>      }
>      return transform;  
> }];
> ```

However, I'm stuck as isNodeInsideFrustum always returns false, even when node A is visible.

2. Change the field of view of the camera itself, to follow the node so that it doesn't go out of view. This however, I have no clue how to get started.

What I'm looking to do is pretty much the same as this SpriteKit question here - [Keeping an object within the screen. Swift SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105898/keeping-an-object-within-the-screen-swift-spritekit)

And yes, since this is ARKit, I realise that node A will change it's position when it's dragged by the edge of a screen.

How can I prevent the node from leaving the field of view?

Comment: what happens if instead of `self.cameraNode` you do `self.sceneView.pointOfView`? Maybe your ref to the main camera is broken?

Comment: @ProBlaster That works! Now I can detect when my node is visible or not. Thank you! self.cameraNode isn't a broken reference, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. Now, I've got to figure out how to stick it to the edge of the screen, and drag it across.